# Google Data Studio - Graphs with variable metrics

Tags: looker-studio

I have a [Treemap](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9381697) that shows me the category specific category of a person. This category is assigned by the sum of different variables. These variables are columns in my Google Data Studio Report.

How can I create something to let me choose which columns use to make this [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212)?

Example:

| Person_ID | A_Score | B_Score | C_Score | ABC_Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 9 |
| 23456 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 11 |
| 96584 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 6 |
| 78542 | 5 | 5 | 2 | 12 |

Actual Variable: `ABC_Sum` = `A_Score` + `B_Score` + `C_Score`

**Objective**:
Be able to have a new variable where I select in a control which columns [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212) and with this value use it in the [TreeMap](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9381697).

Note: All this data comes from a BigQuery Table

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a Parameter for your Datasource name it "Metric Selector"
Step 2: Create a new Field with a Case statement. We Name it "Selected Metric"

```
Case
When Metric Selector = "A_Score" Then A_Score
When Metric Selector = "B_Score" Then B_Score
ELSE "Invalid Metric"
END
```

Step 3: Create a control field and assign it to your Parameter

Step 4: Replace your Metric in your TreeMap with your new Metric "Selected Metric"